# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: secret key byte array cannot be null or empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am using spring-boot with JWT.

**Application.properties**

```
jwt.secret=xyz
```

**Controller.java**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }
```

**JwtTokenUtil.java**

```
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
            Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
            return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
        }

        private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

            return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY*1000)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
        }
```

in the `jwtTokenUtil.generateToken` code I am getting the following error

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: secret key byte array cannot be null or empty.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: secret key byte array cannot be null or empty.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:204)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:88)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:100)
    at net.javaguides.springboot.helloworldapp.config.JwtTokenUtil.doGenerateToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:66)
    at net.javaguides.springboot.helloworldapp.config.JwtTokenUtil.generateToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:60)
    at net.javaguides.springboot.helloworldapp.controller.BasicAuthController.createAuthenticationToken(BasicAuthController.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
```

When I have given my credentials I am getting this error. the application is already validated my credentials, but while generating the token I am getting this error.

**UPDATE:-**

While debugging I have seen the internal code like below

```
 @Override
    public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey) {
        Assert.hasText(base64EncodedSecretKey, "base64-encoded secret key cannot be null or empty.");
        Assert.isTrue(alg.isHmac(), "Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.");
        byte[] bytes = TextCodec.BASE64.decode(base64EncodedSecretKey);
        return signWith(alg, bytes);
    }
```

In this `bytes` I am getting null

Comment: Exception is because the variable 'secret' is null

Comment: @jps error message is clear but I am giving the `jwt.secret=xyz` in application.properties file

Comment: in your code you just use `secret` and it's not clear where or how it is defined: `signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)`. It's a matter of debugging, set a breakpoint and watch your variables.

Comment: @jps I have not given the variable diclaration there but in debugging I am getting `secret` value as `xyz`, I have edited my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your key need to be base64 encoded
See Source:
https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/impl/DefaultJwtBuilder.java#L138

Try following:

```
    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes())
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY*1000)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, encodedString ).compact();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The secret key is too short. I had the same error and just changing from

```
jwt.secret=omg
```

to

```
jwt.secret=HRlELXqpSB
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and my reason was that the code was not able to get secret value, even though it was declared in application properties and i was reading it. After just doing a set of the secret key, it was able to generate token.

Answer (score 0):

your secret key is too short. please use a long one, like more than 10 characters. then it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired
val tokenUtils = JwtTokenUtil()

if you using this class in another class, check @Autowired. its worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).